# How do you count cars in OpenCV with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to count the number of cars in the image automatically using OpenCV and Python.

[image]

Initially I thought I could do this with some segmentation, but I didn't have much success. I then thought that a Hough Transform might help compute the border around the cars but it only really picked out the parking space lines. The only thing I can think of would be to start training some matches on templates of cars and non-cars, but I'm hoping there is something simpler that will do well here.  I also tried edge detection which looks positive but not really sure how to continue:

[image]

Comment: hm, if its picking up the parking space lines, you could do some segmentation as long as the parking space size can be a "given". This is to say, extract the parking lot lines, verify it is a spot with given ratio/size, then check within the spot if there is a car by examining the area within the spot - probably using some analysis of uniformity or something.

Comment: I can't assume that there will always be parking space lines.

Comment: in that case, the V from HSV color space and do some morphological playing around. I'll post some quick rudimentary code to get you started.

Comment: Are you only solving this problem in this specific parking lot? does the camera ever move? You can greatly simplify the problem if the camera and scene are fairly constant. You could create a small region of interest where each spot should be. Then compare the values in those regions to the mean in the street (this will account for day/night variations)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so.... I probably did too much work on this, but it seemed simple enough.

For my implementation I decided it would be better to find empty parking spaces, and assume that all other spaces are occupied. To determine if a spot is empty I simply compared it to a parking space sized portion of the road. This means that this same algorithm should work whether its bright or dark, etc. because the template is extracted directly from the image.

At this point I just do template matching (I tried various methods, but `cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED` worked best). This gives a decent result, and now we need to process it.

[image]

I create the ROIs (regions of Interest) around the parking lot rows. I then collapse them to a single vector by taking statistics per column. I look at the mean. 
[image]

Its a pretty good indicator, you can already clearly see where the empty spaces are. But dark colored cars still present some issues, so now we decide to look at another statistic, how about variance? The parking lot is pretty constant throughout the entire region. A car on the other hand has a few changes, the windows, roofrack mirrors make for some variance. So I plot "inverted" variance. So rather than no change having a variance of 0, it has a variance of 1. It looks something like this
[image]

This looks pretty promising! But you know whats even better? Combining the two! so lets just multiply them together, i called this result the "probability" since it should range between 0 and 1
[image]

Now you can really see the difference between a blank space, and a dark car. So lets do some simple threshold. This is great, but it doesn't give you the NUMBER of vehicles/empty spaces. At this point we go through the "probability" column by column, and we look for a certain number of consecutive pixels over the threshold. How many pixels? about as many pixels as a car is wide. This  "hysteresis" type model should suppress any peaks or spurious data points.

And now it all comes together, we assume the number of spaces is constant(reasonable assumption I think) and we just say the `number of cars = number of spaces - number of empty spaces` and mark the image

[image]

and print some results

```
found 24 cars and 1 empty space(s) in row 1
found 23 cars and 0 empty space(s) in row 2
found 20 cars and 3 empty space(s) in row 3
found 22 cars and 0 empty space(s) in row 4
found 13 cars and 9 empty space(s) in row 5
```

and of course, the code. It might not be the most efficient, but I'm typically a matlab person, its my first openCV/Python project

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# this just keeps things neat
class ParkingLotRow(object):
    top_left=None
    bot_right=None
    roi=None
    col_mean=None
    inverted_variance=None
    empty_col_probability=None
    empty_spaces=0
    total_spaces=None

    def __init__(self,top_left,bot_right,num_spaces):
        self.top_left = top_left
        self.bot_right = bot_right
        self.total_spaces = num_spaces

############################ BEGIN: TWEAKING PARAMETERS ###########################################
car_width = 8       #in pixels
thresh = 0.975      #used to determine if a spot is empty
############################### END: TWEAKING PARAMETERS ###########################################
parking_rows = []

# defines regions of interest, row 1 is on top, row 5 is on bottom, values determined empirically
parking_rows.append(ParkingLotRow((  1, 20),(496, 41),25))     #row 1
parking_rows.append(ParkingLotRow((  1, 87),(462,105),23))     #row 2
parking_rows.append(ParkingLotRow((  1,140),(462,158),23))     #row 3
parking_rows.append(ParkingLotRow((  1,222),(462,240),22))     #row 4
parking_rows.append(ParkingLotRow((  1,286),(462,304),22))     #row 5

#read image
img = cv2.imread('parking_lot.jpg')
img2 = img.copy()

#creates a template, its jsut a car sized patch of pavement
template = img[138:165,484:495]
m, n, chan = img.shape

#blurs the template a bit
template = cv2.GaussianBlur(template,(3,3),2)
h, w, chan = template.shape

# Apply template Matching 
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
#adds bounding box around template
cv2.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 5)

#adds bounding box on ROIs
for curr_parking_lot_row in parking_rows:
    tl = curr_parking_lot_row.top_left
    br = curr_parking_lot_row.bot_right

    cv2.rectangle(res,tl, br, 1, 5)

#displays some intermediate results
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Original, template in blue'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()

curr_idx = int(0)

#overlay on original picture
f0 = plt.figure(4)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)),plt.title('Original')


for curr_parking_lot_row in parking_rows:
    #creates the region of interest
    tl = curr_parking_lot_row.top_left
    br = curr_parking_lot_row.bot_right

    my_roi = res[tl[1]:br[1],tl[0]:br[0]]

    #extracts statistics by column
    curr_parking_lot_row.col_mean = np.mean(my_roi, 0)
    curr_parking_lot_row.inverted_variance = 1 - np.var(my_roi,0)
    curr_parking_lot_row.empty_col_probability = curr_parking_lot_row.col_mean * curr_parking_lot_row.inverted_variance

    #creates some plots
    f1 = plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot('51%d' % (curr_idx + 1)),plt.plot(curr_parking_lot_row.col_mean),plt.title('Row %d correlation' %(curr_idx + 1))

    f2 = plt.figure(2)
    plt.subplot('51%d' % (curr_idx + 1)),plt.plot(curr_parking_lot_row.inverted_variance),plt.title('Row %d variance' %(curr_idx + 1))

    f3 = plt.figure(3)
    plt.subplot('51%d' % (curr_idx + 1))
    plt.plot(curr_parking_lot_row.empty_col_probability),plt.title('Row %d empty probability ' %(curr_idx + 1))
    plt.plot((1,n),(thresh,thresh),c='r')

    #counts empty spaces
    num_consec_pixels_over_thresh = 0
    curr_col = 0

    for prob_val in curr_parking_lot_row.empty_col_probability:
        curr_col += 1

        if(prob_val > thresh):
            num_consec_pixels_over_thresh += 1
        else:
            num_consec_pixels_over_thresh = 0

        if (num_consec_pixels_over_thresh >= car_width):
            curr_parking_lot_row.empty_spaces += 1

            #adds mark to plt
            plt.figure(3)   # the probability graph
            plt.scatter(curr_col,1,c='g')

            plt.figure(4)   #parking lot image
            plt.scatter(curr_col,curr_parking_lot_row.top_left[1] + 7, c='g')

            #to prevent doubel counting cars, just reset the counter
            num_consec_pixels_over_thresh = 0

    #sets axis range, apparantlly they mess up when adding the scatters
    plt.figure(3)
    plt.xlim([0,n])

    #print out some stats
    print('found {0} cars and {1} empty space(s) in row {2}'.format(
        curr_parking_lot_row.total_spaces - curr_parking_lot_row.empty_spaces,
        curr_parking_lot_row.empty_spaces,
        curr_idx +1))

    curr_idx += 1

#plot some figures
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a situation where you may want to exploit the color components of the image. Obviously, a straight threshold on the average luminance value is going to eliminate the cars with dark paint. One possibility would be to explore color relationships (red to green, blue to green, red to blue) as well as saturation. Hue probably won't get you much since most of the cars are strongly grey.

I think your edge detection method could work if you can restrict your region of interest. To get a better edge and eliminate the parking lines use a 2x2 erode filter on the color image before running your edge detect. Then I'd recommend using a stronger edge detection method (like sobel or prewitt). You should get something like this (mine is run on all 3 color channels):

[image: 3 channel sobel edge detect after erosion]

Then you can convert to binary if you want (shouldn't be necessary) or just count pixels in relevant ROIs.

[image: ROIs]

If you are trying to create something for moving cameras, multiple lots, multiple angles, then you will need a much more complicated system. But for a single stationary camera, something like this should work.

Comment: Great question by the way, had fun playing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick matlab code which can be easily converted to python to get you started...

```
b = rgb2hsv(I);
se = strel('rectangle', [2,4]); %# structuring element
BW = b(:,:,3)>0.5; 
BW2 = bwareaopen(BW,30);
BW3 = imerode(BW2, se); 
BW4 = imdilate(BW3, se);
CC = bwconncomp(BW4);
```

From here you know'll need to look at the put results of CC and compute width to height ratio, since you know approximately how large cars are. Here is my out put result from BW4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cars are objects with a high density of corners, so that gives you some additional information to determine whether an image region may be a car. I simply used

```
goodFeaturesToTrack
```

with maxCorners = 10000, qualityLevel = 0.01 and minDistance = 1 and got this result

[image: detected corners on image]

respectively

[image: detected corners]

This alone is very noisy but maybe you can combine it with other segmentation approaches. For example you could calculate an "expected car size rectangle" based on color segmentation and search for such rectangles with a high density of corners. When you have a very structured situation like in the sample image you "know" where a car should be so you can only check these areas.